# Is there a way to simulate a slow standard input/output?

Tags: java, operating-system, processbuilder

Wanted to test a process execution (using Java ProcessBuilder) behaviors when the standard input / output is slow/blocked. Once a process is started, how can slowness (or blocking for sometime) be simulated?

Comment: can you try with input stream as a file and use a thread to have a lock on it for sometime.. so input stream technically is blocked..

Comment: There may be native tools for the operating system you're using. Which os are you using?

Comment: windows and linux

Comment: Simplest solution, I think, would be to wrap the `InputStream` / `OutputStream` in another `InputStream` / `OutputStream` that intercepts calls and sleeps the thread.